# How to tell if a table exists in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper

This code is failing on the last line specifically due to the check for table_exists? How do I correctly do this in Datamapper?

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'DataMapper'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/blog.db")

class Post
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :title, String
    property :body, Text
    property :created_at, DateTime
end

DataMapper.finalize

# automatically create the post table
DataMapper.auto_migrate! unless Post.table_exists?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Justin,

If you have `dm-migrations` required (which basically means that you're using an RDBMS adapter anyway), you can do the following to find out if a table (or column inside that table) exists.

```
# Find out if the table named 'people' exists
DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter.storage_exists?('people')

# Find out if there's a 'name' column in the 'people' table
DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter.field_exists?('people', 'name')
```

Note that these API methods only get mixed into the `adapter` if `dm-migrations` are required and you're using a `DataObjectsAdapter` descendent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DataMapper.auto_update!` which should be non-destructive (adds tables/columns only).

Comment: yeah thank you, that's what I've been doing to work around the issue, however I'd really like to understand what the heck happened to foo.table_exists?